# Eval column name with bracket

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, eval

I am trying to bind a `column` to a `datalist`, and the `column name` is `Standard Size Supported (bytes)`.
And the `datalist` has a `table` which i did it as follows for the `column`:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="1">Standard Size Supported (bytes)</td>
  <td colspan="3">
     <asp:Label ID="lblStandard" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Standard size supported (bytes)")%>' class="form-control"></asp:Label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Upon executing the code, it gives me the error column does not exist. I know it is due to the bracket in the `column` name. i have tried `<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Standard size supported (bytes)"] %>` and `<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "Standard size supported (bytes)") %>`. But it does not work, any idea? It is from an existing system and assuming I cannot rename the `column`.

Comment: Try using `string.format()`

Comment: Why you have such a weird column name? It's in your hand right to simplify it atleast in your server code? Also, why you are using two _Data Binding_ expressions?

Comment: My apologies @RahulSingh, i have edited my post. Unfortunately, it is still not working. Sorry, what do you mean by simplify it? And as i have mentioned, it is from a existing system which is not set up by me. So it beats me too why the column is named as such

Comment: Hi @MuhammedShevilKP, nope it still doesn't work. Upon debug, it only takes up to Standard size supported instead of Standard size supported (bytes)

Comment: @TanStanley - Okay maybe you can't change the database column name, but you can definitely change the model property name which is binding it right?

Comment: @RahulSingh, thank you for your suggestion! i did not think of that, allow me to post the working solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another workaround method which was brought up by @Rahul Singh. 
In select query, i have changed it to

```
"SELECT `Standard size supported (bytes)` as 'Standard' FROM `tableA`
```

And at the aspx file, i have changed the `Eval` to

```
 <tr>
   <td colspan="1">Standard Size Supported (bytes)</td>
   <td colspan="3">
    <asp:Label ID="lblStandardMTU" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Standard") %>' class="form-control"></asp:Label>
   </td>
 </tr>
```